# Does grep work properly on pdf files?

Tags: pdf, full-text-search, grep

Is it possible to search multiple pdf files using the 'grep' command. It doesn't seem to work, how do people search content on multiple pdf files?

Comment: I guess searching via pdftotext is also a viable option http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/searching-pdf-files-grep

Comment: I think it depends a lot on what your actually trying to achieve and this doesn't say much about that. If you're just doing it as a user... if I recall adobe acrobat allows you to search multiple pdf's at once.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I should have seen this earlier Adobe reader does have a capability where you can search in multiple documents via their View-->Search option.

I was under the impression this wasn't there and hence was looking at the grep command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search contents of multiple pdf files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643438/how-to-search-contents-of-multiple-pdf-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [clucene](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clucene/) I think they can do what you want.

Comment: I was just looking for a simple search capability here

Comment: to note: in the future simple search is more of a superuser question, imo. I answered these because these are solutions you might use to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

Well, PDF is a binary format, and grep can search binary files as if they were text

```
grep -a
```

or you can just use pdftotext (which comes with xpdf) like this:

```
pdftotext whee.pdf | grep pattern
```

Comment: I am able to get this command working only if a pass a "-" after the file name to be searched. i.e.

pdftotext whee.pdf - | grep pattern

Comment: Oh, weird...the - means stdout (which is what you need the text to be passed to for the pipe to work properly), which in my shell you don't need to specify afaik.

Comment: This was the only technique I could find that can actually grep 'notes' within a pdf document. The results were a bit messy, but easy enough to cleanup, and at least the technique works. +1.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention which OS you're using, but under Mac OS X you can use `mdfind` from the command line:

```
mdfind -onlyin search/directory/path "kind:pdf search text"
```

Answer (score 2):

Pdf is a binary format, that's why searching it with grep is not that helpful. You can search the strings is a pdf with grep like this:

```
ls dir_with_pdfs/*.pdf|xargs strings|grep "keyword"
```

Or you can use the **pdf2text** command on pdf's and then search result with grep.

Comment: Sorry, that is just nonsense! PDF normally uses compressed objects and even if the objects were uncompressed, the text is only partly written in cleartext inside the pdf.

Answer (score 2):

This tool [pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/) will do the work. It has a syntax similar to grep. To search in several files just a simple shell script. For example:

```
$> ls Documents/*.pdf | xargs pdfgrep -n -H "system"
Documents/2005-DoddGutierrezRO-MAN1.pdf:1: designed episodic memory system
Documents/2005-DoddGutierrezRO-MAN1.pdf:1: how ISAC's episodic memory system is
Documents/2005-DoddGutierrezRO-MAN1.pdf:1: cognitive system employs a combination
....
```

Answer (score 1):

PDF is a binary dump of objects used to display the pages. There may be some meta data you can grep but the actual page text is in a Postscript stream and may be encoded in a variety of ways. Its also not guaranteed to be in any order. You need to think of PDF as more like a Vector image file than a text file.

There is a short article explaining text in PDFs in more detail at http://pdf.jpedal.org/java-pdf-blog/bid/27187/Understanding-the-PDF-file-format-text-streams

Answer (score 0):

If you have pdftotext installed via the popplar package, then try this perl script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $p = shift;
foreach my $fn (@ARGV) {
    open(F,"pdftotext $fn - |");
    while (<F>) { print "$fn:$_" if /$p/; }
    close(F);
}
```