# How to search contents of multiple pdf files?

Tags: linux, pdf, full-text-search, grep, debian

How could I search the contents of PDF files in a directory/subdirectory? I am looking for some command line tools. It seems that `grep` can't search PDF files.

Comment: Grep will not work as PDF is a binary format and the text is often compressed or encoded in a variety of ways.

Comment: Here is a GUI solution: Adobe Reader, see https://wikispaces.psu.edu/display/training/Search+for+Text+in+Multiple+PDFs+with+Adobe+Reader

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/grep-pdf-files

Comment: Adobe reader works fine, but it does not index; so if you have a lot of files, it will be slow. Any indexing solution?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Your distribution should provide a utility called `pdftotext`:

```
find /path -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "your pattern"' \;
```

The "-" is necessary to have pdftotext output to stdout, not to files.
The `--with-filename` and `--label=` options will put the file name in the output of grep.
The optional `--color` flag is nice and tells grep to output using colors on the terminal.

(In Ubuntu, `pdftotext` is provided by the package `xpdf-utils` or `poppler-utils`.)

This method, using `pdftotext` and `grep`, has an advantage over `pdfgrep` if you want to use features of GNU `grep` that `pdfgrep` doesn't support. **Note**: pdfgrep-1.3.x supports `-C` option for printing line of context.

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle The edit "(Edit by -kp-)" you made does no not work since `grep` filters the printed file names.

Comment: @sjr no, while the `pdfgrep` solution is good for really quick and simple searches, often I want to get some context, as a single line won't be helpful enough -- so as I added to this answer: For instance, you can add the -C5 option before "your pattern" to include 5 lines of context to the output -- pdfgrep does not support this

Comment: oh that's cool, glad to know there are advantages to this even though it is much less obvious to most people wtf it is doing

Comment: @sjr Just for the record: I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and `pdfgrep` is useless, it reports a tremendous amount of rubbish on files it cannot handle. Your solution on the other hand helped. So please don't delete it, even after 3 years it is still helpful!

Comment: I was able to use it also in cygwin, altough to make it a function with parameter I had to make the "your_pattern" become '$1'

Answer (score 279):

There is [pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.org), which does exactly what its name suggests.

```
pdfgrep -R 'a pattern to search recursively from path' /some/path
```

I've used it for simple searches and it worked fine.

(There are packages in Debian, Ubuntu and Fedora.)

Since version 1.3.0 [pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.org) supports recursive search. This version is available in Ubuntu since Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal).

Comment: From Natty (Ubuntu 11.04) upwards (See http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pdfgrep&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

Comment: @pavon `pdfgrep` does now have that recursion option, including `-R` to also follow symlinks

Comment: I have a problem with this tool on Debian 10. It does not find some strings which can be found with evince. Turns out to be quite unreliable.

Comment: @Ohumeronen Seven years later, problem remains. Results seem to depend on how pdf was created. So pdftotext -raw (though deprecated) seems to help.

Comment: As of [release 2.0](https://pdfgrep.org/news/pdfgrep-2.0-released.html) `pdfgrep` has a `--cache` option to drastically speed up multiple searches on the same files.

Answer (score 36):

[Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) is a fantastic full-text GUI search application for Unix/Linux that supports dozens of different formats, including PDF. It can even pass the exact page number and search term of a query to the document viewer and thus allows you to jump to the result right from its GUI.

Recoll also comes with a viable command-line interface and a [web-browser interface](https://github.com/koniu/recoll-webui/).

Comment: @Glutanimate It would help (me and possibly others too) if you could add an **example** pertaining to the original question *(command line tool for search of multiple pdf's):* I would also like to see how to perform a **wildcard search** and how to search the **current directory including all subdirectories**. How would that look with `recoll / xapian` in the command line (non-GUI)? Thanks!

Comment: @LeszekŻarna Perhaps you could post the example you tested?

Comment: The `recoll` [user manual](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/usermanual.html) might contain some pointers, but offers a rather technical and "off-topic" read...

Comment: @nutty: recoll -t -q dir:`pwd` ext:pdf 'neuro*' -- stackoverflow ate the backticks around pwd.

Answer (score 19):

My actual version of pdfgrep (1.3.0) allows the following:

```
pdfgrep -HiR 'pattern' /path
```

When doing `pdfgrep --help`:

- H: Print the file name for each match.
- i: Ignore case distinctions.
- R: Search directories recursively.

It works well on my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 18):

There is another utility called [ripgrep-all](https://github.com/phiresky/ripgrep-all), which is based on [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep).

It can handle more than just PDF documents, like Office documents and movies, and the author [claims](https://phiresky.github.io/blog/2019/rga--ripgrep-for-zip-targz-docx-odt-epub-jpg/) it is faster than `pdfgrep`.

Command syntax for recursively searching the current directory, and the second one limits to PDF files only:

```
rga 'pattern' .
rga --type pdf 'pattern' .
```

Answer (score 7):

I made this **destructive** small script. Have fun with it.

```
function pdfsearch()
{
    find . -iname '*.pdf' | while read filename
    do
        #echo -e "\033[34;1m// === PDF Document:\033[33;1m $filename\033[0m"
        pdftotext -q -enc ASCII7 "$filename" "$filename."; grep -s -H --color=always -i $1 "$filename."
        # remove it!  rm -f "$filename."
    done
}
```

Comment: +1. But instead of the `$filename.` you should pipe it into `grep`.

Answer (score 4):

I like @sjr's answer however I prefer xargs vs -exec.  I find xargs more versatile. For example with -P we can take advantage of multiple CPUs when it makes sense to do so.

```
find . -name '*.pdf' | xargs -P 5 -I % pdftotext % - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "pattern"
```

Comment: interesting point about `xargs`' parallel-processing capability. Note that your `--label` option-argument will be _literally_ `{}`, because the `grep` command is now no longer executed in the context of `find`'s `exec`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and thus I wrote a script which searches all pdf files in the specified folder for a string and prints the PDF files wich matched the query string.

Maybe this will be helpful to you.

You can download it  [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B40g4ULDwq3zVEwzRi1ydWFaQlU)

Comment: maybe useful to put the script in the comment?

Comment: i tried your script and it turns out much slower than the `pdfgrep` solution or sjr's one-liner, and it left me with an ongoing process using 100% of a CPU thread even after I Ctrl-C to terminate it.

Answer (score 2):

If You want to see file names with **pdftotext** use following command:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec echo {} \; -exec pdftotext {} - \; | grep "pattern\|pdf"
```

Answer (score 2):

First convert all your pdf files to text files:

```
for file in *.pdf;do pdftotext "$file"; done
```

Then use `grep` as normal. This is especially good as it is fast when you have multiple queries and a lot of PDF files.

Comment: This, when done in combination with `ag` https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher  . Capable to parse at psychedeliks Gb by microseconds. Flat files for life

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source common resource grep tool [crgrep](https://sourceforge.net/projects/crgrep) which searches within PDF files but also other resources like content nested in archives, database tables, image meta-data, POM file dependencies and web resources - and combinations of these including recursive search.

The full description under the Files tab pretty much covers what the tool supports.

I developed crgrep as an opensource tool.

Comment: Craig - do you have a connection to that project? If so, you should state it in your answer. I say this because you've just posted a virtually identical answer to two other old questions ...

Comment: Updated post to clarify that I'm the author of crgrep

Answer (score 0):

You need some tools like pdf2text to first convert your pdf to a text file and then search inside the text. (You will probably miss some information or symbols).

If you are using a programming language there are probably pdf libraries written for this purpose. e.g. http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/ for Perl

Answer (score 0):

try using 'acroread' in a simple script like the one above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the good ideas here!

I tried the xargs method, but as pointed out here, xargs will make it impossible (or very hard) to include printing the actual file name...

So I tried the whole thing with [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

```
parallel "pdftotext -q {} - | grep --with-filename --label='['{}']' --color=always --context=5 'pattern'" ::: *.pdf
```

- This prints not only the **pattern**, but with `--context=5` also 5 lines above and below as well for context.
- With `-q` pdftotext won't print any error messages or warnings (quiet).
- I use brackets `[]` as labels instead of braces `{}`. If you wanted braces `--label='{'{}'}'` will make that happen. Note that `{}` is replaced by the actual filename by GNU parallel, e.g. `'Example portable document file name with spaces.pdf'` (`{}` is already using single quotes `'`).
- By using `--label={}` only the filename will be printed, which may be the favored way of displaying the filename.
- I also noticed that the output was without color when I tried it, except when forcing it by adding `--color=always` with grep.
- It may be useful to add `--ignore-case` to the grep command for a case-insensitive keyword search.

If all PDF files should be processed recursively, including all sub-directories in the current directory (`.`), this can be accomplished through find:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | parallel -0 "pdftotext -q {} - | grep --with-filename --label='['{}']' --color=always --context=5 'pattern'"
```

- With find, `-iname '*.pdf'` acts case-insensitive. With `-name '*.pdf'` only lower-case .pdf files will be included (the normal case). Since I sometimes also encountered Windows PDF-files with an upper-case .PDF file extension, I tend to prefer `-iname`...
- The above command also works with the `-print` find option (instead of `-print0`), so it will be line-based (one file name per line), then `-0` (NUL delimiter) must be omitted from the parallel command.
- Again, including `--ignore-case` in the grep command will make the search case-insensitive.

As a general recommendation when playing with the whole command line, `parallel --dry-run` will print which commands would be executed.

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | parallel --dry-run -0 "pdftotext -q {} - | grep --with-filename --label='['{}']' --color=always --ignore-case --context=5 'pattern'"
pdftotext -q ./test PDF file 1.pdf - | grep --with-filename --label='['./test PDF file 1.pdf']' --color=always --ignore-case --context=5 'pattern'
pdftotext -q ./subdir1/test PDF file 2.pdf - | grep --with-filename --label='['./subdir1/test PDF file 2.pdf']' --color=always --ignore-case --context=5 'pattern'
pdftotext -q ./subdir2/test PDF file 3.pdf - | grep --with-filename --label='['./subdir2/test PDF file 3.pdf']' --color=always --ignore-case --context=5 'pattern'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.org/):

```
pdfgrep -HinR 'FWCOSP' DatenModel/
```

In this command I'm searching for the word `FWCOSP` inside the folder `DatenModel/`.

As you can see in the output you can have the file name wit the line numbers:

[image]

The options I'm using are:

```
-i : Ignores, case for matching
-H : print the file name for each match
-n : prefix each match with the number of the page where it is found
-R : same as -r, but it also follows all symlinks.
```