# Find String withing particular file using grep command in php

Tags: php, linux

I am upload one file which is PDF file and I want to search particular word contains in uploaded

File using only grep command in php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PDF is a binary format and `grep` won't work. You'll have to convert the PDF to text first.

Comment: @Amal , Thanks .. but how to convert it in txt file and then find word using grep command.

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+pdf+to+text+site%3Astackoverflow.com)? This has been answered many times before. Try one of those solutions and if you can't get it to work, update this question (or post a new question) describing the errors / issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pdfgrep see this link [How to search contents of multiple pdf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643438/how-to-search-contents-of-multiple-pdf-files)  I have also used it few times and it also supports recursive search.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Answer (score 2):

As Amal Murali wrote in comment, you have to convert PDF content to text. This has been already solved at StackOverflow, ie [How to extract text from the PDF document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999889/how-to-extract-text-from-the-pdf-document).
Then you can use preg_match_all, or if you really want to use grep, you can use something as proc_open and pass the text through pipe.

So, using class from http://pastebin.com/hRviHKp1 (link from article), here is an example with preg_match_all:

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('Videographer_RFP.pdf');
$a->decodePDF();
preg_match_all ('some pattern', $a->output(), $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Note that I have not tested the code.