# Convert find command to function in order to search in PDF files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following command taken from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4643518/3130747)

```
  find /path -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "your pattern"' \;
```

And i want to turn it into a function along the lines of

```
  pdf_search() { find ./ -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "$1" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "$@"' \; ; }
```

I'm not sure how to do this though, i just want to be able to pass an argument
to the function to use it such as

```
  pdf_search 'look for this'
```

using the command as

```
pdf_search() { 
  find ./ -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "$1" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "$1"' \; ; 
}
```

Gives the following error -

```
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '': No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax of passing parameters to a function is correct (see [details](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/complexfunct.html)). But the problem is with the expansion of the `$1` variable inside single quotes. Please, read accepted answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash-shell-script)

So, after fixing single quotes problem, your code may look like this:

```
pdf_search() {
    find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "$1"' -- "$1" \;
}

pdf_search "your text"
```