# Find specific text in pdf file and print file name and row with text

Tags: pdf, grep, find

I've searched online and I cannot find the answer I need..I need to search recursively in Linux environment through multiple directories for a file named "monthly_spd.pdf" for a key word phrase such as "MOS-corrected" and then print that row where "MOS-corrected" is found and also print the path/filename.

I've tried this below and I can print or display the file/path name but I have not figured out how to print the row where the key word phrase ("MOS-corrected") is found in each file.  Thank you.

```
 find . -name 'monthly_spd.pdf' -exec echo {} \: -exec pdftotext {} - \; | grep "MOS-corrected, r\|pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer here in the link below by adding the "-C5" after "grep" in the solution I tried above for printing the context around the key word phrase, which is exactly what I needed.  See remark/comment from Colin D Bennett!

[How to search contents of multiple pdf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643438/how-to-search-contents-of-multiple-pdf-files)

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
pdfgrep -HinR 'FWCOSP' DatenModel/
```

In this command I'm searching for the word `FWCOSP` inside the folder `DatenModel/`.

As you can see in the output you can have the file name wit the line numbers:

[image]

The options I'm using are:

```
-i : Ignores, case for matching
-H : print the file name for each match
-n : prefix each match with the number of the page where it is found
-R : same as -r, but it also follows all symlinks.
```